# Traveling in Algeria from Europe

Tags: visa-free-entry, moroccan-citizens, algeria

I'm a EU-Moroccan national, and I'd have to travel in Algeria in the future, but as far as Algeria is concerned, it requires a visa for almost every country in the world except its bordering countries' nationals (Morocco and Tunisia) and a few other countries. Can I simply use Moroccan passport for entry and exit in Algeria instead of applying for a visa? Many Arabs told me that I might be blocked because at their say "Arab governments don't accept this switching of passport or tricks" or "they might ask a visa for EU" which is weird because they're supposed to record and see the flux of people pertaining their country. Thought?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The question acknowledges the procedure described in the other question (“switching of passport”) and raises a specific concern. It's definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @Relaxed Thank you, people very often do not understand this subtle difference and do not understand the differences between an open and a closed question, too quick to flag a question as duplicate.

Comment: Note that you could also show both passports to the airline and/or Algerian authorities. One to establish your right to enter Algeria visa-free and the other one to establish that you can enter the EU and don't need a visa. Any reason to believe this should be a concern?

Answer (score 1):

Entering a country visa-free, where this is permitted by the destination country’s immigration rules, is not ‘switching of passport or tricks’. The EU is not a country, there is no such thing as an ‘EU passport’ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passports_of_the_European_Union

You can confirm the entry requirements by checking with the Algerian Embassy or Consulate local to you, rather than paying attention to hearsay. For example, the Visa Exemptions section on the website of the Algerian Embassy in the UK states:

“Nationals from the following countries do not require an entry visa to travel to Algeria:

Libya, Malaysia, Mauritania, Morocco, Sahrawi Arab Democratic Republic, Seychelles, Tunisia and Yemen”.

http://www.algerianembassy.org.uk/index.php/diplomatic-visas.html

A Google search throws up https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php, which states “visa-free/90 days” for Morrocan nationals wishing to enter Algeria.

Timatic, the system used by airlines, says:

“The following are exempt from holding a visa:

Nationals of Morocco for a maximum stay of 3 months. Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.”

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: This travel *does* require “switching” passports in that the OP will need to present his or her EU passport to border guards and the airline (certainly on the way back) but the Moroccan passport to establish the right to enter Algeria. Rightly or wrongly, the OP has heard that this might create problems. Generic info on entry requirements (which is already acknowledged in the question) is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Relaxed The point I was trying to make (possibly badly) is there’s no such thing as an EU passport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passports_of_the_European_Union

Comment: I was just saying I have a passport of one of the members of the EU.

Comment: That wasn't clear at all and completely incidental to the question. The OP simply meant a passport from an EU country accounting for the lack of visa in his Algerian passport. The rest of the issues remain.